# BigDecimal, issue with setScale

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am doing this:

```
(obj.getValue().divide(weight)).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)
```

and I am getting this error :

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no
>   exact representable decimal result.

Where do I need to put the setScale?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I divide properly using BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637232/how-can-i-divide-properly-using-bigdecimal)

Comment: 1/3 is 0.3333333333... . And this is where ``BigDecimal`` fails with having an exact decimal number representation. You may take a look for overloaded methods of [``divide``](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception comes from the `divide` method, so you cannot fix it changing something *after* it's executed. You actually should pass the `MathContext` as the second parameter to the `divide` method itself:

```
(obj.getValue().divide(weight, new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)));
```

This way you explicitly say that you want to divide keeping 3 digits with `HALF_DOWN` rounding mode.

Answer (score 1):

Or you still have the other public method of BigDecimal:

```
public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)
```

Applied to your example:

```
obj.getValue().divide(weight, 3, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
```