# Java - Calculate pi using the Nilakantha series and BigDecimal error

Tags: java, bigdecimal, pi

I've been working on a small program to calculate pi using the Nilakantha series, BigDecimal, and someone else's code - but edited by me.

Here's the code so far:

```
package com.waitdev.pi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the number of calculations you would like to do");

        long no = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());
        long step = 0;
        BigDecimal ans = new BigDecimal(3);
        Double j = 2.0;

        BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal(0.0);

        while (true) {
            step++;
            if ((step % 2) == 1) {
                ans.add(new BigDecimal(4.0 / (1.0 * j * (j + 1) * (j + 2))));
            } else {
                ans.subtract(new BigDecimal(4.0 / (1.0 * j * (j + 1) * (j + 2))));
            }

            j += 2;
            pi = ans;

            if (step >= no)
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Calculated: " + pi);

        BigDecimal enew = pi;
        double error = enew.divide(3.1415926535897932);
        if (error >= 1) {
            double bigerror = 2 - error;
            System.out.println("Your accuracy is: " + bigerror * 100 + "%");
            System.out.println(step);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Your accuracy is: ");
            System.out.print(error * 100);
            System.out.println("%");
            System.out.println(step);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program, the result is this crash report:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method divide(BigDecimal) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (double)

    at com.waitdev.pi.MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:38)
```

It seems to be at this part:

```
double error = enew.divide(3.1415926535897932);
```

In eclipse, this line says 'The method divide(BigDecimal) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (double)'

By the way, I'm new to BigDecimal and I'm also new to Java, while I do know some of the basics.

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637232/how-can-i-divide-properly-using-bigdecimal

Comment: @awadheshv: That is not about the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for `BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), you'll see that there are several overloads for the `divide` function, but none of them has a `double` as argument. That is what the compiler complains about

To be able to use a double, you'll have to use something like

```
        BigDecimal enew = pi;
        BigDecimal pizza = BigDecimal.valueOf(3.1415926535897932);
        double error = enew.divide(pizza, 64, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
                           .doubleValue();
```

---

#### Note

But note that how you use `BigDecimal` here makes no big sense.

Initializing `BigDecimal` with `double`, which you do all the time, is not very precise, and the more you do it, the more you make the use of `BigDecimal` obsolete. Either all calculations are done in `BigDecimal`, and all `BigDecimal` are initialized with strings or integers or by constants or calculations, or you can just as well omit `BigDecimal` altogether and use `double` exclusively.

So again, get rid of `double`, use `BigDecimal` all the time. Also define a `MathContext` with the precision (not too low!) and rounding mode you prefer and use that everywhere.

If that is too much work, or turns out to be too slow, then lose on precision and use `double` instead of `BigDecimal`. But don't mix them the way you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think U need to Use **BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP** like this...

```
BigDecimal c = a.divide(b,2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```