# How to devide a BigInteger by a double in Java?

Tags: java, math, biginteger

The title says it all: How do I divide a `BigInteger` by a floating point number in Java? I don’t need the fraction part of the division, it is okay to have it either rounded or truncated (however I would be interested which one applies).

The “obvious” does not even compile:

```
BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(73).pow(42);
BigInteger y = x.divide(Math.PI); // The method divide(BigInteger) in the type BigInteger is
                                  // not applicable for the arguments (double)
System.out.println(y);
```

I expected this one to work:

```
BigInteger y = new BigDecimal(x).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI)).toBigInteger();
```

Unluckily, it gives an `ArithmeticException`: *Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.* This is true for π, of course…

Of course, this one works, but it is way too slow…

```
BigInteger y = BigInteger.valueOf(-1);
BigDecimal σ = BigDecimal.ZERO;
while(σ.compareTo(new BigDecimal(x)) < 0) {
    y = y.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    σ = σ.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI));
}
```

What’s the correct, canonical way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637232/how-can-i-divide-properly-using-bigdecimal

Answer (score 3):

You have to add [RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) to divide function, otherwise java doesn't know how to round the division and gives you `ArithmeticException`

```
BigInteger y = new BigDecimal(y).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI), RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toBigInteger();
```

All Rounding types are well explained in the documentation link above.

Comment: I agree, one simple approach to get to *one* of the possible solutions. And leaves "space" for my answer ;-)

Comment: If you don't plan on explaining what each of the rounding modes actually do, maybe it's wiser to just use `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` as the standard, since that is what most people are familiar with?

Comment: @AlvinL-B you are right thanks, edited!